# Ionic Live Reload - Takes long time and doesn't save page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 4 project, and I'm using `ionic serve` to test the app. I have 2 issues/questions on this.

1. It takes about 10 seconds to reload every time I want to check a change.
2. It never saves the place in the navigation when it reloads. It always goes back to the root page.

I'm finding these 2 issues very frustrating and difficult to work with. Is there a better way to test and develop Ionic apps? Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can work around these problems, make sure you are using lazy loading to ensure a quicker reload. When you are working at length deep in your app write some code to navigate there automatically on app load, then remove it/adjust it when you need to. For style changes you can make adjustments in the browser dev window while inspecting elements with no reload time, then "finalise" them in your app when you finished tweaking.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. I can't be the first person having this issue. There must be a real solution.

Comment: I am unsure why your system is taking 10 seconds every change which is why i mentioned lazy loading, but you may have a slow system, or there may be some other circumstance with your specific setup/code i am unaware of, i dont have your code to review after all. Every time changes go out to the webserver the "chunck" is reloaded, without lazy loading this chunk can be very large. Your app will return to the root page unless you code it to open on another page. I just place something like this `this.router.navigate(["myPage"]);` in the app.ts constructor.

Comment: Using the browser dev tools to inspect and manipulate elements is common place in web development and we are using css, html and javascript here.

Comment: It taking more like 5 seconds. But that still is a lot when I keep on switching back and forth. How do I set up lazy load? Also it's not so easy to use dev tools with ionic elements since it is rendered into real html.

Comment: A few seconds to reflect changes sounds about right. The html is nested as you would expect, just simply right click on what you intend to fiddle with (assume you are fiddling with css) and change the style.

Comment: So I guess really is no real answer to my questions. I just have to work with it. I appreciate your tips though.

Comment: can you please run `ionic info` the show the output?

Comment: @Shannon, please post your comments as an answer so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around these problems, make sure you are using lazy loading to ensure a quicker reload.

When you are working at length deep in your app write some code to navigate there automatically on app load, then remove it/adjust it when you need to. 
I usually place something like 
`this.router.navigate(["myPage"]);` in the app.ts and change it as needed.

For style changes you can make adjustments in the browser dev window while inspecting elements with no reload time, then "finalise" them in your app when you finished tweaking. I do this by clicking inspect on the element I need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

You have got a network setup problem in your computer.

Check your hostname and reverse DNS resolution. Or you have a firewall that logs many access.